# Equivalent of std::transform for tuples

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I want a function that will behave like `std::transform` for tuples. Basically the functionality to be implemented is

```
template<size_t From, size_t To, class Tuple, class Func>
void tuple_transform(Tuple&& source, Tuple&& target, Func f)
{
    // elements <From, To> of `target` ti become `f(si)`, where
    // si is the corresponding element of `source`
};
```

I believe that to implement this I'll need a **compile time integer range** struct, a generalization of `std::index_sequence` and I've implemented it [here](https://github.com/picanumber/CODEine/blob/master/integer_sequence.h) with `cti::range`. I also believe that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28344369/2567683) type of compile time traversal is ideal here :

```
template<class Func, class Tuple, size_t...Is>
void for_each_in_tuple(Func f, Tuple&& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>){
    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander { 0, ((void)f(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))), 0)... };
}

template<class Func, class Tuple>
void for_each_in_tuple(Func f, Tuple&& tuple){
    for_each_in_tuple(f, std::forward<Tuple>(tuple),
               std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>::value>());
}
```

Can anyone help me with the implementation ?

---

### Notes : On the type of the mutation function

@MohitJain Like in the code linked (tuple_transform) this is not taken into account (`Func` has a single type). If this is solved like that, I could easily extend it by passing a template template parameter `template<class> class Func` and mandate that my transformation types are like this

```
template<typename T>
struct Func
{
    static void apply(T& val) { ... }
}
```

then inside the body of tuple transform, each transformation func could be called like :

```
get<I>(target) = func<typename tuple_element<I, Tuple>::type>::apply(get<I>(source))
```

---

### EDIT

Just gave a lightning talk @ accu 2015. The above was the CodeKata at the end of the presentation. I'll leave [here](http://prezi.com/ijmqjhj0gapp/?utm_campaign=share&utm_medium=copy) the presentation, hopefullly it'll help with any implementation attempts (I think pretty much every tool required is presented, so we'll have more attempts at this)

Comment: in `std::transform` type of each element is same. In `std::tuple`, this type may be different. How do you plan to transform them all with 1 transform function? Is it overloaded, templated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `index_range` from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59059/template-integer-range).

```
template<size_t SN, size_t DN, class TSrc, class TDest, class Func>
void tuple_call_assign(TSrc&& source, TDest& target, Func f)
{
    std::get<DN>(target) = f(std::get<SN>(std::forward<TSrc>(source))); 
}

template<size_t From, size_t To, class TSrc, class TDest, class Func, size_t...Is, size_t...DIs>
void tuple_transform(TSrc&& source, TDest& target, Func f,
                     std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::index_sequence<DIs...>)
{
    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander { 0, (tuple_call_assign<Is,DIs>(std::forward<TSrc>(source),target,f), 0)... };
}

template<size_t From, size_t To, size_t FromDest, class TSrc, class TDest, class Func>
void tuple_transform(TSrc&& source, TDest& target, Func f)
{
    static_assert(To > From, "Range must be increasing");
    static_assert(To <= std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TSrc>>::value+1, 
        "Range must be valid for source tuple");
    constexpr size_t RangeSize = To-From;
    static_assert(FromDest+RangeSize <= std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TDest>>::value, 
        "Range must be valid for target tuple");

    tuple_transform<From,To>(std::forward<TSrc>(source), target, f,
                    index_range<From,To>(), index_range<FromDest, FromDest+RangeSize>());
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/BuT1Xi)

This takes a third template argument to specify a starting index to transform into the target tuple.

Answer (score 4):

The `index_sequence` solution has been mentioned already:

```
template <std::size_t From, size_t... indices, typename T1, typename T2, typename Func>
void transform(T1&& s, T2& t, Func f, std::index_sequence<indices...>)
{
    (void)std::initializer_list<int>{
        (std::get<indices+From>(t) = f(std::get<indices>(std::forward<T1>(s))), 0)...};  
}


template <std::size_t From, std::size_t To, typename T1, typename T2, typename Func>
void transform(T1&& s, T2& t, Func f)
{
    transform<From>(std::forward<T1>(s), t, f, std::make_index_sequence<To-From+1>());
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/761f8000a76b65a5).

Comment: How to implement this, when Func needs to be a function template?